# RecyclerView crashes when used in fragment but not in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I was using a recyclerview in an activity and now decided to use it in a fragment instead. Now my code crashes at `layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager (globalContext);` with a *NullPointerException*.

I have no idea why. As I said it worked perfectly fine when used in activity.

I'm using Xamarin but that really doesn't make any difference.

I have only included the first parts of the code as app crashes before reaching others.

```
private Context globalContext = null;
        RecyclerView recyclerview;
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager;
        NewsAdapter adapter;

        public LatestNewsFragment()
        {
            this.RetainInstance = true;
        }

        public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_latestnews, null);

            // Get our RecyclerView layout:
            recyclerview = view.FindViewById<RecyclerView> (Resource.Id.recyclerView);

            return view;
        }

        public override async void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            globalContext = this.Context;

            //............................................................
            // Layout Manager Setup:

            // Use the built-in linear layout manager:
            layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager (globalContext);

            // Plug the layout manager into the RecyclerView:
            recyclerview.SetLayoutManager (layoutmanager);

            //............................................................
            // Adapter Setup:

            // Create an adapter for the RecyclerView, and pass it the
            // data set to manage:

            var rest = new RestAccess();    
            var listofarticles = await rest.ListArticlesAsync("somesource", "1");
            adapter = new NewsAdapter (listofarticles, globalContext);

            // Register the item click handler (below) with the adapter:
            adapter.ItemClick += OnItemClick;

            // Plug the adapter into the RecyclerView:
            recyclerview.SetAdapter (adapter);
        }

        // Handler for the item click event:
        void OnItemClick (object sender, int position)
        {
            // Display a toast that briefly shows the enumeration of the selected photo:
            int photoNum = position + 1;
            Toast.MakeText(globalContext, "This is card number " + photoNum, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
```

Edit:

So I changed the `OnCreateView` to :

```
public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_latestnews, null);

    // Get our RecyclerView layout:
    recyclerview = view.FindViewById<RecyclerView> (Resource.Id.recyclerView);

    // Plug the layout manager into the RecyclerView:
    recyclerview.SetLayoutManager (new LinearLayoutManager (Activity));

    return view;
}
```

And still getting nullpointer exception at `recyclerview.SetLayoutManager (new LinearLayoutManager (Activity));`

Edit 2:

variable `recyclerview` is actually null. Don't know why.

**Answer:**
My app was crashing for two reasons:

1- layoutmanager must be defined in `OnCreateView` but I was doing it in `OnActivityCreated`.

2- My fragment layout file didn't include the RecyclerView.

Comment: Can u post fragment_latestnews layout file

Comment: @Raghavendra, Thanks for the notice. That was the problem. As I said I was using this RecyclerView in an activity before, now I changed to fragment but forgot to actually add recyclerview to the layout file for fragment. That fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `LayoutManager` in `onCreateView()` after initializing `RecyclerView`, instead of setting in `onActivityCreated()`:

```
mRecyclerView =  (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(newLinearLayoutManager(mRecyclerView.getContext()));
```

Comment: See the edit. I changed the `OnCreateView` like you said. still crashes.

Comment: Actually, `recyclerview` is null. For some reason the `FindViewById` is giving null.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `this.Context` use `getActivity()` to get Context in Fragment class. Change:

```
globalContext = this.Context;
```

to

```
globalContext = getActivity();
```

Comment: Still crashes with the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `getActivity()`

```
layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager (getActivity());
```

Comment: I also did what you suggested. In Xamarin, `Activity` equivalent to `getActivity()` in Java.

Comment: as the sample from Xamarin, you can check out
https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/android5.0/RecyclerViewSample/RecyclerViewSample/RecyclerViewFragment.cs